# crm dynamics online, pass custom url parameter to plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dynamics-crm

I want to create a plugin that reads a custom parameter from the url. I found this
piece of code

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/madenwal/2011/04/15/retrieving-querystring-paramaters-in-a-crm-plug-in/

When I tried implementing it for this call

```
  var reference = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["parameter_reference"]
```

I got the following error:

System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.

I tried to resolve this by applying an attribute to the assembly, shown in this post:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/839300/how-to-use-the-allowpartiallytrustedcallers-attribute-to-call-an-assembly-that-has-a-strong-name-from-a-web-page-by-using-visual-c-.net,-visual-c-2005-or-later-versions

I was not sure what security permissions where needed for httpcontext i.e FileIOPermission or PrincipalPermission. So I ended up using the SecurityPermission option.

However this did not resolve the issue. Any ideas will be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably getting that error because your plugin is running within the sandbox.

[Plug-in isolation, trusts, and statistics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg334752.aspx)

> Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online & on-premises) support the execution of
>   plug-ins and custom workflow activities in an isolated environment. In
>   this isolated environment, also known as a sandbox, a plug-in or
>   custom activity can make use of the full power of the Microsoft
>   Dynamics 365 SDK to access the organization web service. Access to the
>   file system, system event log, certain network protocols, registry,
>   and more is prevented in the sandbox.

You could try moving your plugin outside of the sandbox  - look for isolation mode during plugin registration.

However, I would suggest taking a different approach entirely - such as reading data from record fields. Reading from the query string is a bit unusual and the query string format has been known to change between CRM versions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Our environment is online so would not be able move the plugin out of sandbox. The scenario is a bit of an unusual one, but I ended up implementing a work around that uses the record id as a reference (instead of a custom param) to query the external service.